# inode number is changed suddenly at certain location in c programming on linux

Tags: c, linux, systems-programming, inode, readdir

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>


void creatEnv();

char *mygetcwd(char *buf, size_t size) {
  DIR  *dirp_p, *dirp_c;
  struct dirent *dp; 
  ino_t cwd_inode;
  dirp_c = opendir("../../.."); //open current working directory
  dirp_p = opendir("../.."); //open parent directory
  printf("\n");

  /* find inode of current working directory */
  printf("--below this,list of runner\n");
  while((dp = readdir(dirp_c))!= NULL){
    printf("fileN : %s  inode : %lu\n",dp->d_name,dp->d_ino);
  }
  printf("\n--below this,list of as3\n");
   while((dp = readdir(dirp_p))!= NULL){
    printf("fileN : %s  inode : %lu\n",dp->d_name,dp->d_ino);
  }
  return buf;
}

int main(void) {
  pid_t pid;
  int status;
  char buf[255];

  creatEnv();
  chdir("dir/sub");

  printf("original func: %s\n", getcwd(NULL, 0));
  printf("%s\n", mygetcwd(buf, 255));

  return 0;
}

void creatEnv(){
  mkdir("dir", 0755);
  mkdir("dir/sub", 0755);
  mkdir("dir/sub2", 0);

  creat("dir/a", 0755);
  creat("dir/b", 0755);
  creat("dir/sub/x", 0755);
  symlink("dir/a", "dir/sl");
  symlink("dir/x", "dir/dsl");
}
```

Result is weird.
at first part of a picture below, as3 inode is 1024015,

[image]

but at second part, "." inode(this have to be same as as3 inode) is 256
and for some reason ".." inode is 256.
Why does this happen? I cannot find reason.
Only btw these two dirctories, The weird result is evoked.
In other directory, It works quite well.
I compiled and ran this code on repl.it!

Comment: That looks like something is mounted at /home/runner/as3. Try using the mount command to tell you what it is.

Comment: I ran your code on a normal directory structure (no extra mount points) and the inodes match.

Comment: the problem was related to repl.it's environment.